# How could I get the username and password of the windows in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, azure

I have login in windows and try to get the username and password of the windows in an application. FYI, the application is hosted in the other server, We fetch the access through the IP.
Is it any option to get the logged user name and password of the windows and pass to the application in JavaScript.
IS IT possible.?
Please help

Comment: Which protocol are you using to get the access in windows from your server ?

Comment: HTTP/HTTPS protocol

Comment: I don't think so, whatever protocol you use to get access in a machine , you will not get raw username or password . If someone has credentials of that machine he might access that machine using supported protocols by that machine and look around inside it. :)

Comment: Since a user's password isn't stored anywhere there's no way for you to retrieve it.

Comment: is there any ADFS protocol, which is used to get the value????

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, you cannot retrieve the password of a Windows user.

Not even if the user is yourself and you're logged in to Windows on the machine on which you are trying to get the password from.